# How Many Times a List It Is Inside Another List Using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Supose I have a list of integers

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int> { 1, 4, 1};
```

I want to find out how many times another List it is inside this one.For instance

```
List<int> l2 = new List<int> { 1 , 1 } occours 1 time. 

List<int> l3 = new List<int> { 4, 1 } occours 1 time.

List<int> l4 = new List<int> {1} occours 2 times.

List<int> l5 = new List<int> {6,4,1} occours 0 time.

List<int> l5 = new List<int> {4,1,1} occours 1 time.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason you're getting downvoted is because you haven't demonstrated that you've tried to solve the problem yourself. Post your best attempt at it and we may help you.

Comment: I am getting trouble with repeating values using Intersect .

Comment: This problem is in fact not simple.

Comment: Does the order matter? I don't understand why `4,1,1` is a 'match' given the wrong order, while `4,1` only matches once rather than twice.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst The way I interpreted it, {4,1} only matches once because each time you use one of the subsets you "spend" it, so you can only use the 4 once.

Comment: The order does not matter. Each individual element in l5 is contained in l1.

Comment: Magnus you are correct !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea here is to create a dictionary that maps each element in the original list to how frequently it occurs. I then iteratively decrement each item corresponding to one in the sub-list until one of the values reaches zero, at which point I return the number of complete iterations.

```
public static int CountSubsets<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> subList)
{
    var grouped = list.GroupBy(t => t).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count());
    int count = 0;
    while (RemoveSubset(grouped, subList))
        count++;
    return count;
}

private static bool RemoveSubset<T>(Dictionary<T, int> dict, IList<T> subList)
{
    foreach (T item in subList)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(item) && dict[item] > 0)
            dict[item]--;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Not necessarily the most efficient or most elegant solution, but it should work.

Edit: Here's a fancy-schmancy but probably slower way of doing it. I'm pretty pleased with this one:

```
public static int CountSubsets2<T>(this IList<T> list, IList<T> subList)
{
    var main = list.GroupBy(t => t).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count());
    var sub = subList.GroupBy(t => t).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Count());
    return sub.Select(t => main.ContainsKey(t.Key) ? main[t.Key] / t.Value : 0).Min();
}
```

Comment: Both implementations doesn't work for the first test case.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Yes it does. It returns 1: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/FhimCk3liUW5YMfwx8U4Sw

Comment: All testing and by understanding the algorithm here, I'm pretty sure that the first works OK, not tested the second.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken Sorry, mixed up the parameters.

Comment: Magnus all tests worked fine.I was expecting a single line solution.

Comment: Well, you can write my second solution in a single line if you like. I can't think of an easier way to do it, but there may be one. There's definitely nothing built-in in Linq though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest solution and working.

```
    public int GetCount(List<int> source, List<int> innerList)
    {
        source = source.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
        innerList = innerList.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
        int count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= source.Count - innerList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (source.Skip(i).Take(innerList.Count).SequenceEqual(innerList))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Is this the one you needed ??
Thanks.